# Can you provision a credit card in Google Pay from an Instant App

Tags: android-instant-apps, android-tap-and-pay

I works for a bank that is considering using an instant app (and AppClip on iOS) to provision a newly approved credit card with both our card App and Google Pay. I know you cannot take payments, but does that mean you are locked out of TapAndPay completely? Would you be able to provision a card in Google Pay from an Instant App?

Answer (score 1):

So after communication with Google Tap and Pay support, and trial and error -- the answer is yes. You can access TapAndPay; however, you can not recieve or make payments from an instant App.

Comment: are you saying that Google said you can provision credit cards from Instant Apps? (and just not receive/make payments?)

Comment: Yes and in release. You cannot make purchases -- yet -- although apple allows it in App-clips.

Comment: Thanks for following up :) We were able to make a proof of concept Instant App with the TapAndPay SDK to add cards to Google Wallet. So, it's definitely possible!